# What's the equalivent of 'CV_IS_SEQ_CLOSED' in opencv2?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am migrating an old program written in opencv 1 C API to opencv2 with C++, and the old code uses 'CV_IS_SEQ_CLOSED' to check if a contour is closed or not. I googled a lot but couldn't find how to do the same thing with opencv2. So is there a workaround to do exactly the same thing?

Comment: How are you getting your contours? A simple check if the first and last elements of the vector are equal might suffice.

Comment: @Aurelius I am using findContours to get contours. Your idea sounds correct, but is it guaranteed that a 'closed contour' must have the first and last element equaled?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `cv::findContours()` doesn't give information about the open- or closed-ness of the contours it produces. Additionally, closed contours are not guaranteed to have the same start and end point. If you are generating contours without approximation (by passing the `CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` flag), then checking that the distance between the first and last point of the contour is less than `sqrt(2)` should suffice:

```
// 1.5 is approximately sqrt(2)
bool closed = cv::norm(contour.front() - contour.back()) < 1.5;
```

I don't think this is guaranteed using a different approximation method.